# Convert from epoch time to date UTC+2 hours

Tags: oracle, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm trying to pull data from an Oracle DB table and I'm able to convert the time column correctly, however it's -2 hours from what it should be.

Bear in mind that `StartTime` column is in Epochtime.
Can you please explain to me what is wrong with my query?

Column names are:
`Description`, `StartTime`

```
select Description,
       TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(CAST(
          DATE '1970-01-01' + (1/24/60/60/1000) * StartTime as TIMESTAMP),
         'America/New-York'),
         'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as StartTime 
  from MyTable
```

I tried to change the `America/New-York`, but it ended up with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i solved my problem:

```
select TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' + (1/24/60/60/1000) * StartTime AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as StartTime
from MyTable
```

hope that will help others.